# How to map composer vendor folder to docker volume ? (case of Symfony bundle linked to my projet)

Tags: php, docker, symfony, composer-php

I am stuck with that problem.

I have a docker compose file with volumes mapping that way :

```
 volumes:
  - ./:/var/www/html:rw
  - ../epossobundle/:/var/www/epossobundle :rw;
```

In composer.json, there is a repo linked on a bundle which I am working on it like this :

```
  "repositories": [
{
  "type": "path",
  "url": "../epossobundle"
},
```

But when I start my container I got the error

> Warning: include(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../epo/api-auth-sso-bundle/EpoApiAuthSsoBundle.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

How can I do ??

PS : It is not possible to install something in Docker image because it is intranet network

Thanks a lot
Serge

Comment: Perhaps you need to install the dependencies in the container because you do not transfer the `vendor`. Try running `docker exec <container_id_or_name> "composer install --no-dev"`. Assuming you have composer installed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `vendor` file is missing dependencies, specifically `epo/api-auth-sso-bundle/EpoApiAuthSsoBundle.php` so you'll need to install them.

Grab a root shell inside the container:

```
docker exec -it -u root <container_id_or_name> /bin/bash
```

Install composer (requires root):

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Then install your dependencies (if not in production, no need for `--no-dev`):

```
composer install --no-dev
```

Finally, change the permissions back (`ls -rvla`):

```
# Nginx
chown -R nginx:nginx .
# Apache2
chown -R www-data:www-data .
```

Note: This is a "hacky-fix", if you rebuild the container you will have to do this every time. You should look to do this inside your `Dockerfile` as a permanent solution.

Untested example of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Nginx
RUN groupadd -g 101 nginx && \
    useradd -u 101 -ms /bin/bash -g nginx nginx

# Apache2
RUN groupadd -g 101 www-data && \
    useradd -u 101 -ms /bin/bash -g www-data www-data

# Download and install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Nginx
USER nginx
# Apache2
USER www-data

# Or add this as an entry-point (runs as user for permissions)
RUN composer install --no-dev
```